# How to remove _next/image?url in image url Nextjs

Tags: image, url, next.js

I'm using `Nextjs@13` and use `Image`.

Here is my code:

```
<Image src="/download.jpeg" alt="" width={200} height={170} />
```

The image in `/public`.

The `url` result I get:

`/_next/image?url=%2Fdownload.jpeg&w=256&q=75 1x, /_next/image?url=%2Fdownload.jpeg&w=640&q=75`

Expected url: somethings like
`/download.jpeg`.

Although I can access image by `localhost:3000/download.jpeg`

Comment: I think this is part of Next.js optimization for images. Is't causing a specific problem? You can always use a normal `img` tag.